# force unconditional shutdown

Tags: shutdown, systemd

I have encountered a small shutdown problem with a media center PC using NFS and a TV Card. I got this problem partially solved with autofs and recent drivers and Kernel (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS).

The problem is that sometimes at the shutdown process it hangs. I cannot really reproduce it, because it happens rarely but it does happen.

My question is as follows for such situations: Is there a way to set a time limit in which the shutdown occurs no matter what the system is going? I would like to set a timer for 30 minutes or something. If up to this point the system is still turned on and something is pending it should turn off, no matter what.

Comment: The best answer is to find out what's wrong with the shutdown. Processes can sometimes hang during shutdown, making the actual shutdown takes minutes, instead of seconds. Next time this occurs, hit the `ESC` key and you'll see a screen full of text telling you what it's doing. Look at the last line for the clue.

Comment: You should be able to do this using systemd. Take a look at [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd) and [this](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd).

Comment: No response with ESC. I will try to log more and let you know...